# Java web service got unmarshalling error. Is it possible to fix it on server side?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have java web service. I generate wsdl using apache-cxf. Other developer use generated wsdl to create client on some specific accountant program.

When this client trying to invoke web method I can see unmarshalling error - soap message contains unexpected namespace.

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Falut Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element(uri:"my.namespace.here", local:"documentNumber"). Expected elements are <{}id>,<{documentNumber}>,{here list of other DTO fields}.
```

Example of request I expected to get

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:publicInnerInvoiceDocument xmlns:m="my.namespace.here">
            <arg0>
                <documentNumber>String</documentNumber>
            </arg0>
        </m:publicInnerInvoiceDocument>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I got this message using Altova xml spy - tool for creating request using wsdl description. My service work good with it.

Example of message i got from other client

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:publicInnerInvoiceDocument xmlns:m="my.namespace.here">
        <arg0 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
            <m:documentNumber>000001</m:documentNumber>
        </arg0>
        </m:publicInnerInvoiceDocument>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Client developer say he have no tools to control request creation. Platform he use do it automatically and do it wrong.

My best idea to fix it is to handle soap using @HandlerChain and correct soap message I got. I don`t even know is it possible.

I don`t like it. Do you have any other ideas?
Can it because of wrong web service description?

Comment: This client works fine with my service if web method use only simple types like strings or enums